# Get maximum supported cpu frequency in linux kernel space

Tags: linux, kernel, cpu, frequency

I have found that clk_get_rate() returns the current frequency, but is there any function or way of finding out maximum frequency supported in linux kernel space?

Answer (score 0):

From my box:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
1666000 1333000 1000000
```

Following the implementation of this `/sys` entry, may give the desired answer.